# I want to update a tag in real time tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update the label `t6` every time I insert a value to the `entryProd` automatically, but I don't know how to do it :(

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.constants import CENTER, LEFT, S
from tkinter.font import BOLD, Font
from datetime import datetime
import pyodbc
from pyodbc import *
Fecha= datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.conexionBD=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server};'
                                'SERVER=JEFFERSON-PC;'
                                'DATABASE=MegaMercado;'
                                'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        print("Base de datos conectada")
        self.master=master
        self.config(bg="white")
        self.config(width="1000 ", height="570")
        self.pack()
        #TEXTOS
        self.t1=tk.Label(self, text= "Facturacion", font=("Roboto Mono",20,BOLD), bg="white").place(x=400, y=20)
        self.t2=tk.Label(self, text= Fecha, font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=440, y=55)
        self.t3=tk.Label(self, text= "No. Factura", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=437, y=75)
        self.t4=tk.Label(self, text= "Codgio cliente:", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=195, y=130)
        self.t5=tk.Label(self, text= "Codigo producto:", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=185, y=165)
        self.t6=tk.Label(self, text= "", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white")
        self.t6.place(x=500, y=165)
        self.t7=tk.Label(self, text= "Cantidad:", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=255, y=200)
        self.t8=tk.Label(self, text= "Precio", font=("Roboto Mono",12), bg="white").place(x=500, y=200)
   
        #RESUMENES
        frame=tk.Frame(master,width=209,height=100)
        frame.config(bg="white",highlightbackground="gray",highlightthickness=1)
        frame.place(x=667,y=446)
        self.cantidadt=tk.Label(frame, text= "Cantidad:", font=("Roboto Mono",9,BOLD), bg="white").grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.subtotalt=tk.Label(frame, text= "Subtotal:", font=("Roboto Mono",9,BOLD), bg="white").grid(column=0,row=1)        
        self.ITBISt=tk.Label(frame, text= "ITBIS:", font=("Roboto Mono",9,BOLD), bg="white").grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="e")
        self.totalt=tk.Label(frame, text= "Total:", font=("Roboto Mono",9,BOLD), bg="white").grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="e")
        self.valorcantidadt=tk.Label(frame, text= "99999", font=("Roboto Mono",10), bg="white").grid(column=1,row=0,sticky="e")
        self.valorsubtotalt=tk.Label(frame, text= "9999999", font=("Roboto Mono",10), bg="white").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky="e")
        self.valorITBISt=tk.Label(frame, text= "9999999", font=("Roboto Mono",10), bg="white").grid(column=1,row=2,sticky="e")
        self.valortotalt=tk.Label(frame, text= "99999999", font=("Roboto Mono",10), bg="white").grid(column=1,row=3,sticky="e")

        #ENTRYS
        self.productoCod= tk.IntVar()
        self.entryCli=tk.Entry(self, width=18,  font=("Roboto Mono",8), bg="#f9f9f9").place(x=355,y=135,height=23)
        self.entryProd=tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.productoCod,width=18,  font=("Roboto Mono",8), bg="#f9f9f9").place(x=355,y=168,height=23)
        self.entryCant=tk.Entry(self, width=18,  font=("Roboto Mono",8), bg="#f9f9f9").place(x=355,y=203,height=23)
        
        #TABLAS
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Roboto Mono', 8)) 
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Roboto Mono', 9, BOLD)) 
        self.grid1= ttk.Treeview(height=7, columns=("#0","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5"), style="mystyle.Treeview")
        self.grid1.place(x=130,y=280)
        self.grid1.column("#0",width=75)
        self.grid1.heading("#0", text="Codigo", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#1",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#1", text="Producto", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#2",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#2", text="Precio", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#3",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#3", text="Cantidad", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#4",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#4", text="Subtotal", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#5",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#5", text="ITBIS", anchor=CENTER)
        self.grid1.column("#6",width=100)
        self.grid1.heading("#6", text="Total", anchor=CENTER)

        #BOTONES 
        self.agregar=tk.Button(text="Agregar",font=("Roboto Mono",10,BOLD),fg="#f9f9f9",bg="#41ba10", activebackground="#41ba10",activeforeground="#f9f9f9")
        self.agregar.place(x=355,y=240,width=100)
        self.eliminar=tk.Button(text="Eliminar",font=("Roboto Mono",10,BOLD),fg="#f9f9f9",bg="#f00", activebackground="#f00",activeforeground="#f9f9f9")
        self.eliminar.place(x=480,y=240,width=100)
        self.generar=tk.Button(text="Generar",font=("Roboto Mono",10,BOLD),fg="#f9f9f9",bg="#56ABFF", activebackground="#56ABFF",activeforeground="#f9f9f9")
        self.generar.place(x=355,y=450,width=100,height=40)
        self.limpiar=tk.Button(text="Limpiar",font=("Roboto Mono",10,BOLD),fg="#f9f9f9",bg="#56ABFF", activebackground="#56ABFF",activeforeground="#f9f9f9")
        self.limpiar.place(x=480,y=450,width=100,height=40)

    def buscarNombreProducto(self):
        codigo=self.productoCod.get()
        cur=self.conexionBD.cursor()
        sql="Select Prod_Nombre from Productos where Prod_codigo={}".format(codigo)
        cur.execute(sql)
        x=cur.fetchall()
        for i in x:
           self.t6.config(text=str(i[0]))
        

root=tk.Tk()
frame= Application(master=root)
while True:
    frame.buscarNombreProducto()
    frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have removed the Spanish text from the question as StackOverflow is an English-only website, but you can post in Spanish on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ if you want.

Comment: Hey! I am no expert with tk so I can't really help but I would recommend you reducing your code at max before posting a question, most of your code is irrelevant for what you are asking. This is going to help you get an answer faster as more people will actually take the time to read it.

Comment: Look at [tkinter variable tracing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tracing-tkinter-variables-in-python/).

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `while True` loops when using `tkinter`.

Comment: Tracing works very good, I did what I want. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you connect an `Entry` object to a `Label` object.

Make them share a `StringVar`

```py
root = tk.Tk()

data = tk.StringVar( value = "Message" )
entry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = data, width=20)
entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

label = tk.Label( root, textvariable = data)
label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Look at OP's code. OP doesn't put whatever is in the `Entry` inside the `Label`. I think that they use the entry's contents and run it through their database.

Comment: The question seems fairly straight forward, 'update the `label` every time I insert a value to the `entry` automatically'

Comment: In the question it doesn't say update the label with value in the entry. Also look at OP's `buscarNombreProducto` method.

Comment: @TheLizzard, yes it does. Label `t6` to `entryProd`. Automatically

Comment: No. First it uses `cur.execute(sql)` and `x=cur.fetchall()`. Then it configures `self.t6` based on `x`. The data is passed into the database and the result is put in the label not the entry's contents.

Comment: If you want to fix OP's code then good one, I've answered the question that was asked, so I'm done with it.

Comment: I am saying that this answer's code isn't compatible with the question's code.

Comment: Well the adjudicators disagree with you.

Comment: Who are *the adjudicators*?